# ВареньЯ или вареньЕ

Tags: окончания

Как будет правильно? Хочу вареньЯ или хочу вареньЕ?

Answer (score 3):

Падеж выбирается по смыслу:

***Хочу варенья***. Здесь Р.п.,  **неопределенное** значение (хочу варенья вообще).

Ты будешь мед? — Нет, ***я хочу варенье,*** а не мед.  Какое ты будешь варенье? — ***Я хочу вишневое.***

Если говорится о **конкретно** указанном предмете, то обычно используется В.п.

http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm  §203. Различные предложно-падежные формы при одном управляющем слове

**Различие между формами винительного и родительного падежа** может заключаться в том, что первый указывает на определенный предмет, а второй – на предмет неопределенный.